# Construct method returning the complete class Object even when I call some other function

Tags: php, oop

Here is my class code first,

```
class Gateway extends Gateways
{
public function __construct($id = false)
{
    parent::__construct();

    if($id) return $this->getById($id);
}

public function getById($id)
{
    $this->gateway_select->columns($this->cols)->where(array($this->columns['ID'] => $id, $this->columns['IS_ACTIVE'] => 1));
    return $this->_fetch();
}

protected function _fetch()
{
    $this->gateway_select->limit(1);
    //echo $this->sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($this->gateway_select);
    $result = $this->sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($this->gateway_select)->execute()->current();
    return $result;
}
```

and now when I call this code in my some other file

```
$gatewayRow = new Gateway($gatewayId);

print_r($gatewayRow);
exit;
```

The output comes out is the Gateway class Object instead of the database row fetched from getById($id) method, but as per my knowledge, the return needs to be the database row.

When I call getById() method separately, like `$gateway->setById($id);` it works, so its something with __construct()

parent::__construct code

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->db = TechMediaStudios::dbInstance();
    $this->sql = TechMediaStudios::sqlInstance();
    $this->gateway_select = $this->sql->select()->from($this->table);
    $this->_getColumns();
}
```

Comment: what your parent constructor is doing ? if its returning something it will not goto the next like you have in the sub class...

Comment: parent construct is just setting some properties, that's all, it returns void, see the question updated.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot `return` anything from a constructor, period. A constructor can only set up the object or throw an exception, it cannot return anything. Wherever you write `new Foo`, the result will be an object instance of `Foo` and nothing else. This cannot be overridden.

Comment: And that is great for a good reason. Otherwise we would end up with lying API's that give you Animals when you actually wanted to have Cars.

Comment: okay I got that, but I want to achieve results this way,`$gatewayRow = new Gateway($gatewayId);

print_r($gatewayRow);
exit;` Is this possible ?

Comment: @Gagan No, it's not possible. At the very least it'll have to be `$row = (new Gateway($gatewayId))->fetch()`.